Trigger for Start of File Upload
I want to add a JS listener to a shiny app, that gets triggered when a file-upload starts (not when the fileupload is clicked, not when the reactive value in shiny changes, which happens after the file has uploaded, but instead I want it to be triggered when the file is selected from the file menu and "Open" is clicked and the upload actually starts).
The background is, I want to tell the user how long a file-upload (from their computer to my shiny app) took in total.
For this I want to create a JS eventlistener that sets a reactive value to the current time so that I can take the difference later on when the upload has finished.
Note for this example I use alert(1) to figure out when the code is executed, I will use Shiny.setInputValue(id, value); later on.
MWE
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(r"(
    $(document).on("shiny:inputchanged", function(event) {
      if (event.name === "file") {
        alert("shiny:inputchanged file: trigger too late (same as observeEvent(...))!");
      }
    });
  )")),
  fileInput("file", "Upload File") |> 
    tagAppendAttributes(onclick = "alert('onclick file: trigger too early and duplicated?!');")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    showNotification("File has been uploaded: Trigger too late")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Failed Attempts
I played around adding an onclick attribute to the fileInput but this fires before the upload begins (eg when the user needs a long time to select the file to be uploaded, the timing would be off). (fileInput("file", "File") |> tagAppendAttributes(onclick = "alert(1)"))
Also not working, I added JS code that listens to inputchanged, but this fires after the upload is completed.
$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
  if (event.name === 'file') {
    alert(1);
    console.log('#file has changed');
  }
});


Thanks to Kevin's answer, I found the onInput and ondrop trigger, which does exactly what I want (see also this)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Upload File") |> 
    tagAppendAttributes(onInput = "alert('Just Perfect')",
                        ondrop = "alert('Just Perfect')")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

The full time-measuring code
Just in case anyone is interested in the full time-measuring code:
library(shiny)

js_fun <- "
const current_time = (e) => {
  const d = new Date();
  return d.toISOString()
};"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js_fun))),
  fileInput("file", "Upload File") |> 
    tagAppendAttributes(onInput = "Shiny.setInputValue('upload_start_time', current_time());",
                        ondrop = "Shiny.setInputValue('upload_start_time', current_time());")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    fs <- file.size(input$file$datapath)
    td <- as.numeric(
      difftime(Sys.time(),
               as.POSIXct(input$upload_start_time, tryFormats = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ"),
               units = "secs")
    )
    txt <- sprintf("File '%s' has been uploaded: start at %s; took %s for %s resulting in %s/s",
                   input$file$name,
                   input$upload_start_time,
                   prettyunits::pretty_sec(td),
                   prettyunits::pretty_bytes(fs),
                   prettyunits::pretty_bytes(fs/td))
    cat(txt, "\n")
    showNotification(txt)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

